# Javascript way to save user action in browser

Tags: javascript

I was learning about browser local storage, not sure if it is the right way to do it. But Here is the pen that I created.
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/sabipu/pen/rqrKLJ)

**HTML**

```
<button id="switch">Turn lights off</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.light-on {
  background: #000;
}
```

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#switch').click(function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('light-on');
  });
});
```

I wanted the black-background (when lights turned off) stay there when people revisit the website or if it is a real website and a user navigates between pages I don't want to lose the light change that a user did.

Is it possible with Javascript?

Comment: Use localStorage for that

Comment: You aren't actually storing it anywhere yet. Are you just asking if Local Storage is the right way to go?

Comment: java != javascript

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
    <body onload="myFunction()">
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#switch').click(function() {
          $('body').toggleClass('light-on');
           window.localStorage.setItem("bkColor", "#theCurrentColor");
       });
    });      

    func myFunction() {

       if (window.localStorage.getItem("bkColor") != null) {
             document.body.style.backgroundColor = window.localStorage.getItem("bkColor");
        }

    }
```

Comment: `nil`=>`null` or you'll throw ref error. (and `"#theCurrentColor"` is probably not what OP will want to save.

Comment: Sorry, I am an iOS developer now, that why I wrote nil by mistake :)